# Difference between @@ and @ in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

My question is **What is the difference between declaring variables by using @ and @@**?

In SQL Server 2008 R2:

**Example**:

Syntax 1:

```
Declare @a int = 1

select @a;
```

Syntax 2:

```
Declare @@a int = 1

select @@a;
```

Both does the same job here. Then why should we use double @@?

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Why I get down vote for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. The rules for variables state that they start with an '@' character and follow the rules for identifiers.

Since '@' is a valid identifier character, you can have as many as you like at the start of your variable name. However, if you match a system function which has the same name as your variable, then the query will not compile.

In previous versions of SQL Server @ described a local variable and @@ describe a global variable. Now (SQL 2008) @@ is used for a function name so @@ shouldnt be used as a parameter name.

Books OnLine ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx

if any other problem comment me :)